# Attribute Selection for Spring MVC-built Web Services, both XML and JSON

Tags: rest, spring-mvc

Does anyone have a great idea plus maybe code samples on how to implement attribute selection similar to Facebook for Spring MVC-built Web Services? Our web services are RESTFul, currenctly support JSON and XML. My idea is to create a filter that will use the "fields" parameter if present to reduce the response json file. For XML, it might be a bit more challenging.